# free-jqgrid extend viewModal

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In jqgrid (v4.4.5) I extend the default behavior like this:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.view, {
    width:300,
    beforeShowForm: function(form) {
        //hide the edit icon inside id value
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#v_id').find('span:first').css('display','none');
        }, 100);
    }
});

var orgViewModal = $.jgrid.viewModal;
$.extend($.jgrid,{
    viewModal: function (selector, o){ 
        console.log(selector, o);
        $(selector).center();
        orgViewModal.call(this, selector, o);
    }
});
```

I use free-jqgird (v4.12.1-pre) in one project recently and most of things work as expected.
One thing I can't make it to work is to extend the ViewModal. 
The $.jgrid.view works, but not the viewModal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free jqGrid made caching of some methods to reduce a little the size of js file. It saved `$.jgrid.viewModal` in the variable, which one can't overwrite. I removed the caching now (see the latest changes posted [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/bb4937b1f85d058f2b2a1216a83bc72b6e374d89)). You can download the latest free jqGrid from the [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/).

Comment: Thank you very match Oleg, your help is realy appreciated.
One thing I have to point out (in case is helpfull to someone else) is that in free-jqgrid if you give to the selector {top:0px, left:0px} (at the extend) it goes to the beginning of the grid and not of the window as jqgrid(v4.4.5) goes.

That is more helpfull to me but is confusing at the beginning.

Comment: @mad.net: You are welcome! The position of dialogues of jqGrid was changed multiple times and multiple bugs are fixed too. I tried to hold compatibility to the previous versions, but it's not always possible.